# Using the Internet Archive’s Wayback Machine as a CDN

Tags: cdn, static-content, internet-archive

Can the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org)’s [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org) be used as a [content-distribution network](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/content-distribution%20network) (CDN)?

Aside from the moral problem of stealing bandwidth from an organization I love, would serving a unique file from the Wayback Machine serve the same purpose, and provide the same benefits, as serving that file from a CDN?

Comment: See also [Can I use imgur as a CDN?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/52833/can-i-use-imgur-as-a-cdn)

Comment: I'm using github pages for my most of content like javascript, css, images, zip files etc.....they provide 100GB soft bandwidth/month and 1GB storage/repository(you can have multiple repository)... That is I think enough for most of sites...Regarding web archive, no site clear such a thing in their policy page, so it's better to ask them directly. If they think your content will helpful for others community members, like some Ebooks or documentary, then they might approve, but still you should ask them as above link mention about imgur.

Answer (score 8):

No. In fact the Internet Archive is not a CDN. Following your own link we see

> A content delivery network, or content distribution network (CDN), is a geographically distributed network of proxy servers and their data centers. The goal is to provide high availability and performance by distributing the service spatially relative to end users

But while the Internet Archive has backups of its holdings, it does not have a network of proxy servers or distribute its service spatially to end users. Their site is also not optimized in the other ways that a CDN is optimized.

If the goal is to use it to offset the bandwidth usage of a site, it would be highly unethical to misuse their service in that way, and also failure-prone, since if they discovered improper use of their servers, they could easily ban your site and disrupt your service.

Comment: Bizarrely, it's now happened in the wild - https://www.theregister.com/2020/07/03/barclays_bank_javascript_wayback_machine/